# Why am I getting null in onCreate? How can I initialise

Tags: android

it might be a trivial question, if so I'm sorry-I'm new to Java. Basically, I'm trying to set list equal to a sharedPreference that is saved. However the app keeps on crashing because the list is null to begin with. As you can see I have tried to initialise it. I need list to be public because I use it in another method.
The crash log is the following: **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0** In the logs, when I run it, it shows this ** is Correct is: [] ** which I want it to be {1,1,1,1,1,1} to begin with.

So the relevant code looks something like this

```
    public int[] list = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        if (list == null) {
           for (int i : list) {
              list[i] = 1;
           }
       }

       list = getFromPrefs("updateList");
       Log.i("is Correct is ", Arrays.toString(list));
   }
```

Comment: You're calling `getFromPrefs` but you don't show that function. Also, you did not include your crash log.

Comment: Please provide crash log

Comment: Added crashlog in the main question. @Blackbelt thank you for saying that but I had, just someone edited it and removed it (for some reason). I have added it back in now.

Comment: @kodi I don't feel that code is relevant, the main issue is initializing the array, list. But thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] list = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    if (list == null) {
         list=new int[SIZE];
        // The SIZE should be whatever you want
        for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++) {
            // Add 1 to the list
            list[i]=1;
        }
    }
    list = getFromPrefs("updateList");
    Log.i("is Correct is ", Arrays.toString(list));
}
```

}

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. What I was trying to do is say if the list is empty, then set it equal to {1,1,1,1,1,1}. and then continue with the code.

Comment: Although you should also keep in mind that the statement
 list=getFromPrefs("updateList")

would still be getting called. So, if sharedpreferences returns null, your list variable would be again null. So, do manage that functionality accordingly.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I have added an else statement to make sure it doesn't return null again. This code still doesn't work. It still prints **is Correct is: []** to the logs when it should be [1,1,1,1,1,1], to begin with. Thank you for your time, much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked what value you have of your list in SharedPreferences. See, as I can understand by your code is this. You have already declared and initialized a list with a array of 1's. So, your list is not equal to null and will go to else part of the condition which gets value from SharedPreferences. Would be better if you do a debug on this  Activity. This way you would get a much clearer picture.